# Output report with -lt but not with -gt or -eq

Tags: powershell, file, datetime, comparison, datetime-format

Why does   **{$_.LastAccessTime -lt (Get-Date).adddays(-2)}**   give a proper output but if I change the operator to -eq or -gt then I get a blank report?

Comment: It works for Where-Object {$_.lastaccesstime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-5)} but does not work for -eq or -ge operators and gives a blank report. I checked manually and know for sure that there are many files that fall in the range of -eq and -ge. Any idea why?

Comment: @Tughralm - when you use `Get-Date` you get the current date AND the current time. so ... are you SURE that the full datetime for the files in question pass that test? if you want to test with just the date part, use `(Get-Date).Date` and that will give you midnite - the time part will be set to zero.

Comment: @Tughralm Still having any trouble here? If so, choose some example files and pipe them to `Select-Object -Properties LastAccessTime | %{(Get-Date $_).toString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:ffff')}` and post the output in your question. Tell us for which shown dates what does not work.